# How to display data in child component when passed from parent component in Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

This is my School Class.

```
public class School{

public List<Students> Student{get;set;}

public School(){
Student = new List<Students>();
}
```

}

```
public class Student{
public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I created a new object of this class in the parent Razor component and sending a List of Students.

```
@page"/parent"
<Child Data="@s.Student"/>

@code{
public School s = new School(); 
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync(){
s  = await getSchoolStudents("api");
}
```

This is Child Component. Data is not coming from parent to child. And I want to send the data further in js interops.

```
 @page"/child"
@typeparameter T

@code{
[Parameter]
public List<T> Data{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: It seems as though my answer was not useful to you, right ? Shall I delete it ? Ever heard of the phrase "Thank you?"

Comment: Sorry, Thanks for the answer but not useful enough, I already tried this but the issue remains. Data is not being displayed. @enet